# Django: "Can't convert 'Name' object to str implicitly" on saving object

Tags: python, django, postgresql, typeerror, psycopg2

In Django admin, I have created a Name object with name: "United Kingdom". I then create a Nation object with the Name object I've just created, and a path to a flag image.

On saving the entry, I get:

### TypeError at /admin/display/nation/add/

```
Can't convert 'Name' object to str implicitly
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/display/nation/add/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    Can't convert 'Name' object to str implicitly
Exception Location: \models.py in __unicode__, line 24
```

### Relevant section of models.py

```
class Name(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Name: ' + self.name
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'name'

class Nation(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Nation: ' + self.name
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Name)
    flag_path = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'nation'
```

From the error message I understand that `return 'Name: ' + self.name` needs to get a string back to append to 'Name: ', but how would I amend my models.py to allow that?

Comment: What about `return 'Name: ' + self.name.name`?

Comment: `return 'Name: ' + str(self.name)` ??

Comment: pNre, that seems to fit what I want to do best, and works. Could you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change that fixed the problem:

'Name: ' + self.name.name

That way I'm correctly referring to the name column in the name table.

Answer (score 1):

Use unicodes in `__unicode__()` method i.e.

```
u'Name: ' + self.name
```

and

```
u'Nation: ' + self.name
```

Without unicode in `'Nation: ' + self.name`, it will try to get *string* representation which is not defined for `Name` object.