# Can't convert Model object to str implicitly

Tags: python, django, django-models

Similar question [Django: "Can't convert 'Name' object to str implicitly" on saving object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891872/django-cant-convert-name-object-to-str-implicitly-on-saving-object) .It didn't work for me.
Here are the relevant models.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name = 'e-mail')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.name
```

It encounters an error when self.author.name is encountered.
Error message:"Cant convert 'Author'object to str implicitly".

Comment: What versions of Django and Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3 and Django 1.8

Comment: Please show the code that you are running when this error happens, and the full traceback.

Comment: There was a syntax error in the views file.I've fixed it now.Thanks!

Comment: It couldn't hurt to include the wrong code you had, and how you fixed it by answering your own question in case others run into the same problem. Good work fixing it!